# Grouping controls under a single form element

Tags: asp.net

Consider this snippet of code...

```
<form runat="server">
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TextBoxOne" />
    <asp:Button  runat="server" ID="SubmitOne" OnClick="ButtonOne_Click" />

    <hr />

    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TextBoxTwo" />
    <asp:Button  runat="server" ID="SubmitTwo" OnClick="ButtonTwo_Click" />
</form>
```

I want to group these two sets of controls.

When the user presses ENTER, having filled out *TextBoxOne*; the `ButtonOne_Click` event fires. And when the user has typed something into *TextBoxTwo* and presses enter; the `ButtonTwo_Click` event gets fired.

The way you would normally do this, is to have form elements surround each of the groups. But this is not possible in ASP.NET. And short of doing some "has-focus"-logic in JavaScript, I'm all out of ideas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an `<asp:Panel runat=server DefaultButton="SubmitOne">` around the pair.

```
<form runat="server">
   <asp:Panel runat="server" DefaultButton="SubmitOne">
      <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TextBoxOne" />
      <asp:Button  runat="server" ID="SubmitOne" OnClick="ButtonOne_Click" />
   </asp:Panel>
<hr />

   <asp:Panel runat="server" DefaultButton="SubmitTwo">
      <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TextBoxTwo" />
      <asp:Button  runat="server" ID="SubmitTwo" OnClick="ButtonTwo_Click" />
   </asp:Panel>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks. Although it overrides browser default actions on for instance drop-down controls. But that's a brain-fart on the .NET developers side. Can't blame you for that :)